# run function in ajax loaded page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, jquery

Im trying to run a function when I load a ajax page.
In index.html Im loading page1.html, and in page1.html I have a function that I want to run when the page is loaded.

I have tryed many things but no luck.

Lets say I just want to run a function with an alert in it, how would that look?
Thanks!

Im using jquery to get the page1.html.
In page1.html I have the following code to get some albums from facebook, and I simply want to run the code when the page is loading?

```
alert('onload');

//get album name
FB.api('/1424613333333/albums', function(response) {

  if (response && response.data && response.data.length){
    var ul = document.getElementById('fb-albumslist');
    for (var i=0, l=response.data.length; i<l; i++) {
     if (response.data !== "undefined"){    
      var
        album = response.data[i],
        li = document.createElement('li'),
        a = document.createElement('a');
        if(!album.link) continue;
      a.innerHTML = album.name;
      a.href = album.link;
      li.appendChild(a);
      ul.appendChild(li);

    }
   }
  }

  });
 FB.XFBML.parse( document.getElementById('fb-albumslist') );

}
```

And Im using this to load the ajax pages:

```
function loadPage(url) {

      $('#guiden_menyn').load('manmade/guiden/guiden_menyn.html #content', hijackLinks);

      $('#container').load(url + ' #content', hijackLinks);

}
function hijackLinks() {
    $('#guiden_menyn a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        loadPage(e.target.href);
    });


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by an 'ajax page'?

Comment: Do you use plain Javascript or a framework in your website?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible. But you can call function manually after ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery load (http://api.jquery.com/load/). It gives a callback to after the load has completed

Answer (score 0):

This is one way - parse the response, extract the scripts, and then eval them

[Execute JavaScript within responseHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129393/execute-javascript-within-responsehtml/3130915#3130915)